# Get a column value when a specific date is found

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a column value on a specific day, and when it's not that day, fill rows with `float('nan')`

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == '2000-03-20 00:00:00':
        df['event'] = row['close']
    else:
        df['event'] = float('nan')
```

The `df['event']` return `nan` even on the specified day `2000-03-20 00:00:00`

```
df.loc['2000-03-20 00:00:00', 'event']
nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorized solutions are e.g. with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) - if need omit times use [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html) and compare with `Timestamp`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2000-03-19', periods=10, freq='9H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'close': range(10)}, index=rng)

df['event'] = df['close'].where(df.index.normalize() == pd.Timestamp('2000-03-20'))
print (df)
                     close  event
2000-03-19 00:00:00      0    NaN
2000-03-19 09:00:00      1    NaN
2000-03-19 18:00:00      2    NaN
2000-03-20 03:00:00      3    3.0
2000-03-20 12:00:00      4    4.0
2000-03-20 21:00:00      5    5.0
2000-03-21 06:00:00      6    NaN
2000-03-21 15:00:00      7    NaN
2000-03-22 00:00:00      8    NaN
2000-03-22 09:00:00      9    NaN
```

Or use [`partial string indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing):

```
df.loc['2000-03-20', 'event'] = df['close']
print (df)
                     close  event
2000-03-19 00:00:00      0    NaN
2000-03-19 09:00:00      1    NaN
2000-03-19 18:00:00      2    NaN
2000-03-20 03:00:00      3    3.0
2000-03-20 12:00:00      4    4.0
2000-03-20 21:00:00      5    5.0
2000-03-21 06:00:00      6    NaN
2000-03-21 15:00:00      7    NaN
2000-03-22 00:00:00      8    NaN
2000-03-22 09:00:00      9    NaN
```

---

```
rng = pd.date_range('2000-03-19', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'close': range(10)}, index=rng)

df['event'] = df['close'].where(df.index == '2000-03-20 00:00:00')
print (df)
            close  event
2000-03-19      0    NaN
2000-03-20      1    1.0
2000-03-21      2    NaN
2000-03-22      3    NaN
2000-03-23      4    NaN
2000-03-24      5    NaN
2000-03-25      6    NaN
2000-03-26      7    NaN
2000-03-27      8    NaN
2000-03-28      9    NaN
```

Reason why not working your solution is in loop overwrite column `event`, because assign not by index. But is not recommneded, because slow. For learning here is changed your solution:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index.normalize() == pd.Timestamp('2000-03-20 00:00:00'):
        df.loc[index, 'event'] = row['close']
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'event'] = float('nan')
print (df)
                     close  event
2000-03-19 00:00:00      0    NaN
2000-03-19 09:00:00      1    NaN
2000-03-19 18:00:00      2    NaN
2000-03-20 03:00:00      3    3.0
2000-03-20 12:00:00      4    4.0
2000-03-20 21:00:00      5    5.0
2000-03-21 06:00:00      6    NaN
2000-03-21 15:00:00      7    NaN
2000-03-22 00:00:00      8    NaN
2000-03-22 09:00:00      9    NaN
```

---

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == pd.Timestamp('2000-03-20 00:00:00'):
        df.loc[index, 'event'] = row['close']
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'event'] = float('nan')
print (df)
            close  event
2000-03-19      0    NaN
2000-03-20      1    1.0
2000-03-21      2    NaN
2000-03-22      3    NaN
2000-03-23      4    NaN
2000-03-24      5    NaN
2000-03-25      6    NaN
2000-03-26      7    NaN
2000-03-27      8    NaN
2000-03-28      9    NaN
```

Comment: ```cpi = pd.read_csv('cpi.csv')
cpi_dates = []
for i, r in cpi.iterrows():
 cpi_dates.append(r['timestamp'])``` How to use the following line with a list of date `df['event'] = df['close'].where(df.index == cpi_dates)
`

Comment: @x945 - instead `cpi_dates = [] for i, r in cpi.iterrows():  cpi_dates.append(r['timestamp'])` use `cpi_dates = cpi['timestamp']`. For my solution need `df = pd.read_csv('cpi.csv', index_col='timestamp',parse_dates='timestamp')` for `DatetimeIndex`

Comment: @x945 - btw, here is explanation why not loop - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2901002